# Android card view error on touching Card view

Tags: android, android-cardview

I want to get a toast message on touching each card with that Card name:

[image]

XML code on Android

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/album_cover_height"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="clikimage"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Java code

```
public void clikimage(View view){



        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cliked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

In this code same toast is coming for each card..

> The texts came from this code .

.

```
/**
     * Adding few albums for testing
     */
    private void prepareAlbums() {
        int[] covers = new int[]{
                R.drawable.album1,
                R.drawable.album2,
                R.drawable.album3,
                R.drawable.album4,
                R.drawable.album5,
                R.drawable.album6,
                R.drawable.album7,
                R.drawable.album8,
                R.drawable.album9,
                R.drawable.album10,
                R.drawable.album11};

        Album a = new Album("True Romance", 13, covers[0]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Xscpae", 8, covers[1]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Maroon 5", 11, covers[2]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Born to Die", 12, covers[3]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Honeymoon", 14, covers[4]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("I Need a Doctor", 1, covers[5]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Loud", 11, covers[6]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Legend", 14, covers[7]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Hello", 11, covers[8]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Greatest Hits", 17, covers[9]);
        albumList.add(a);



        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

All the Cards are entered manually. I want to set more cards and put it in a loop. Please Help .

XML TITLE CODE.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/album_cover_height"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="clikimage"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/album_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/album_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/count"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/overflow"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_height"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_margin_top"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dots" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Error When Pasted ImageView Listner Code..

```
08-09 11:35:07.453 3079-3079/com.example.jithin.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.jithin.myapplication, PID: 3079
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jithin.myapplication/com.example.jithin.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.jithin.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:113)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: what's ur Error ??

Comment: It stopped Working When i tried this code in My MainActivity on OnClick ...... { public void clikimage(View view){

    //    String textFromTextView = ((TextView)view.getParent().findViewById(R.id.songTitle)).getText();




        TextView aa=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
        String textFromTextView = aa.getText().toString();

        String[] ss = {textFromTextView.toString()};
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Clicked  "+ss[2], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cliked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

Comment: Catch the Error in Logcat

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get text for your toast from the view, 
you need to change this "Clicked" string inside your toast into text from the view.
You didn't show us where is the textView containing the title but if it is in the same RelativeLayout as this ImageView, then you could do something like:

```
String textFromTextView = ((TextView)((RelativeLayout)view.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.title).getText();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, textFromTextView, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Can you show the xml code where the TextView with title is?

Comment: I Tried this code too in  my MainActivity..                                          public void clikimage(View view){

    //    String textFromTextView = ((TextView)view.getParent().findViewById(R.id.songTitle)).getText();




        TextView aa=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
        String textFromTextView = aa.getText().toString();

        String[] ss = {textFromTextView.toString()};
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Clicked  "+ss[2], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cliked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

Comment: Why do you use findViewById on R.id.songTitle, there is nothing like that in your posted xml.
Try to change it just into those 2 lines i wrote

Comment: Where i should paste that code inside the OnClick Method of ImageView ??

Answer (score 0):

You could try attaching a click listener directly to the ImageView like so:

```
      ImageView mThumbnailImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
      .....
      mThumbnailImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Cliked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
            }
        });
```

You might also want to remove:

```
android:onClick="clikimage"
```

from

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/album_cover_height"
     android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:onClick="clikimage"
     android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

as well as the 'clikimage' method implmentation from your Activity. Hope this helps.

Comment: Its getting Error. It stopped working. I pasted that code inside the OnCreate method.

Comment: Thanks, looks like you are attaching your listener to the ImageView even before it is initialized. If you are using a RecyclerView to show your list / grid of items, attach your listener in onCreateViewHolder() *after* inflating each list item.

Same applies to a ListView. Either way the inflation needs to happen in your adapter not the activity *after* the view for each card item is inflated.

Comment: Thank You.. Can u please show me the code Which I have to add

Comment: The same code as in this answer. Find where your CardView is initialized (this should be in your adapter). Then attach the click listener to the imageview. And do not forget to remove the android:onClick = "clikimage" tag from your xml and its corresponding implementation from your activity.

Comment: Now The error is gone .. I Implemented OnClickListner where my card view is initialised and pasted this code inside onclick. But no Toast is comming while clicking.. and i remove onclik from xml code

Comment: Could you please show how you are attaching your listener, this is the last part of the puzzle. Just the place where you call setOnClickListener would do.

Comment: What do you mean by 'pasted this inside onClick' ? After the card view is initialized attach the listener to the instance of the imageView (basically copy the code in this answer and paste it after the cardview is initialized). Your Toast also needs a context (which is actually MainActivity.this, if this is not there you need to pass a context instead). And you should be able to see a Toast. Also try changing the length of the Toast from Toast.LENGTH_SHORT to Toast.LENGTH_LONG to make it display for a longer duration.